# Difference between GD and SGD in one dimensional data

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I know that from https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/36450/what-is-the-difference-between-gradient-descent-and-stochastic-gradient-descent
"While in GD, you have to run through ALL the samples in your training set to do a single update for a parameter in a particular iteration, in SGD, on the other hand, you use ONLY ONE or SUBSET of training sample from your training set to do the update for a parameter in a particular iteration. If you use SUBSET, it is called Minibatch Stochastic gradient Descent."

So can we conclude that GD and SGD are always identical when input and out put are one dimension?

Comment: In order for them to be equivalent you would need a sample size of $1$.

Comment: SGD will be identical to GD when the whole training set is used in both cases. It is not a matter of dimension but a matter of examples/data points.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. So, in the case of minimizing the concave function without any training data (just finding optimal point mathematically), they will be identical right?

Comment: In that case, it is only meaningful to consider deterministic gradient descent, because you only need (and must) to calculate the gradient of the objective function once in each iteration.